# Description logic representation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**If Manufacturer manufactures electronic equipment, then manufacturer generates e-waste.**

**I have generated the triple.**

However how to represent the if-then statement in DL?

```
manufactures(manufacturer, electronic eqpt)
generates(manufacturer, e-waste)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  What's "DL"?  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Is there some concept you're unsure on that is preventing you from being able to answer the question yourself?

Comment: DL stands for Description Logic i.e. a decidable fragment of first order logic. i am creating an owl ontology for e-waste domain. So how to represent above.

Comment: Please edit the question to address the comments, and so that all information can be found in the question itself, rather than in the comments.  We want questions to stand on their own, so that people don't have to read the comments to understand your question.  Thank you!